# getWorkingMemoryEntryPoint not available in Drools

Tags: drools

I'm new to drools.
I need to add a entry point for a kSession and insert objects in the workingMemoryEntryPoint. I have followed the example 1 from the below mentioned reference. 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession&method=getWorkingMemoryEntryPoint

When I try to do the same i cannot find any getWorkingMemoryEntryPoint in the kSession.

[image: details of what i see in my eclipse]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in the tutorial you are following is for Drools version 5.x. 
In Drools 6.x you need to use `KieSession.getEntryPoint(name)` to get a reference to an EntryPoint.

KieSession javadoc: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/

Specific method javadoc: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/rule/RuleRuntime.html#getEntryPoint-java.lang.String-

Hope it helps,